# Is a single member replica set OK?

Tags: mongodb, replication

I am trying to find an authoritative answer to the following question: *Is a single member replica set a supported deployment setup?*

While this question may seems weird or silly, my specific use case follows:

A team wants to upgrade from Mongo 2 to Mongo 4 and they foresee that transactions might be useful to them. They currently run a single mongod instance. MongoDB documentation leads them to believe that to use transactions they must activate replica sets **and deploy at least 3 mongod instances**. Interesting documentation bits are:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/#transactions-and-replica-sets

> Multi-document transactions are available for replica sets only. Transactions for sharded clusters are scheduled for MongoDB 4.2 [1].

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-members/

> The minimum recommended configuration for a replica set is a three member replica set with three data-bearing members: one primary and two secondary members. You may alternatively deploy a three member replica set with two data-bearing members: a primary, a secondary, and an arbiter, but replica sets with at least three data-bearing members offer better redundancy.

My point of view is that:

- Replica sets aim to increase redundancy and availability through a typical primary - secondaries design
- Replica set documentation focuses on what make sense for its initial orginal purpose. It documents traditional and sane deployment setups fo HA (>= 3 and odd number of voter, separate machines, how to deal with multiple DC etc.)
- Team is not interested in HA but must switch to replica sets in order to use TX (alternative path being to forgo TX and deploy a single mongod)
- According to replica set documentation and my distributed systems background, I don't see why a single member replica set would be an issue if you don't care about HA. With a single member a primary can be elected, replication is NOOP and default and majority write concern are just `w: 1`.

Am I right?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/462780/does-a-mongodb-replica-set-require-at-least-2-or-3-members